# ORDER BY too slow in Foreign Table using postgres_fdw

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-fdw, foreign-data

PostgreSQL v9.6, [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/postgres-fdw.html)

**Foreign table**

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE user_info (
  id bigint ,
  info jsonb 
) 
SERVER server_test_fdw OPTIONS(SCHEMA_NAME 'public', TABLE_NAME 'user_info_raw' );
-- user_info_raw is a large table (100 million records, 200 GB)
```

**Sample data of `info`  column**

```
{"key1": 1, "key2": 0.678}
{"key1": 1, "key2": 1.0}
{"key1": 1, "key2": 0.986} 
{"key1": 2, "key2": 0.75}
{"key1": 2, "key2": 0.639}
```

**Query on foreign table**  (*updated*)

```
SELECT id, info 
FROM user_info
WHERE info ->> 'key1'= '1' -- OR using jsonb_extract_path_text(info, 'key1')  = '1'
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT 10; 

Limit  (cost=10750829.63..10750829.65 rows=10 width=40) (actual time=550059.320..550059.326 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=10750829.63..10751772.77 rows=377257 width=40) (actual time=550059.318..550059.321 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: id
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
         ->  Foreign Scan on user_info (cost=100.00..10742677.24 rows=377257 width=40) (actual time=1.413..536718.366 rows=68281020 loops=1)
               Filter: ((info ->> 'key1'::text) = '1'::text)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 7170443
 Planning time: 4.097 ms
 Execution time: 550059.597 ms
```

**Query on user_info_raw**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT id, info 
FROM user_info_raw
WHERE info ->> 'key1'= '1'
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT 10;

 Limit  (cost=0.57..1296.95 rows=10 width=59) (actual time=0.043..0.073 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using idx_user_info_raw_info on user_info_raw  (cost=0.57..68882850.88 rows=531346 width=59) (actual time=0.042..0.070 rows=10 loops=1)
         Filter: ((info ->> 'key1'::text) = '1'::text)
 Planning time: 0.192 ms
 Execution time: 0.102 ms 

select pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('user_info_raw'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 223 GB
```

It takes **10 milliseconds** to execute the query on the **user_info_raw** (*remote server*).

But, It takes **a lot of time** when using the`user_info`foreign table. When I remove `ORDER BY id`, the query executes **very fast**.

I think that my query on *foreign table* *should send to the remote server* for executing, but it's not, I don't know why, may be due to of this excerpt from [postgres_fdw document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/postgres-fdw.html)

> By default, only WHERE clauses using **built-in operators and functions**
>   will be considered for execution on the remote server. Clauses
>   involving **non-built-in functions** are checked locally after rows are
>   fetched. If such functions are available on the remote server and can
>   be relied on to produce the same results as they do locally,
>   performance can be improved by sending such WHERE clauses for remote
>   execution

**How can I fix the issue related to ORDER BY in foreign table  ?**

---

**UPDATED**

Adding `use_remote_estimate` on `server` and `foreign table` doesn't help.

Comment: Can you provide the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the above `SELECT` statement?

Comment: @EvanCarroll : the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on `foreign table` took over 1 hour to execute but not finished, so I cannot provide that info, sorry about that.

Comment: Try at the very least then `ANALYZE`

Comment: @EvanCarroll updated `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Sort operation* is performed on local postgres server, *not on remote*. If your code always sort the results, you
>   can just *create a view on remote postgres* with *order by* clause and
>   then create a foreign table pointing to the view.

**On remote server, adding a view**

```
CREATE VIEW vw_user_info_raw
SELECT id, info 
FROM user_info_raw
ORDER BY id
```

**On local server, create foreign table references to that view**

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE user_info (
  id bigint ,
  info jsonb 
) 
SERVER server_test_fdw OPTIONS(SCHEMA_NAME 'public', TABLE_NAME 'vw_user_info_raw' );
```

*Refer to* [Postgres Admin Forum](http://www.postgresql-archive.org/ORDER-BY-too-slow-in-Foreign-Table-using-postgres-fdw-td5971688.html)

Answer (score 1):

LIMIT pushdown is fixed in PostgreSQL 12.

Here is the discussion https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/87pnz1aby9.fsf@news-spur.riddles.org.uk.

Here is the commit https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/d50d172e517c1d2aabff3ceb3ad3113b909c5017.